# How can I programmatically move textboxes in a word document to another page

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following VBA code selects textboxes in a word document that contain a specific text. How can I programmatically move every textbox to another page (let's say the first page) preserving it's position relative to the page. The original textboxes are positioned absolute to the page they are on.

```
Sub searchTexboxes()
'
' searchTexboxes Macro
'
'

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sTemp As String
Dim nrTextboxes As Integer

nrTextboxes = 0
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        shp.Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
        sTemp = Selection.Text
        sTemp = Left(sTemp, 1)
        If sTemp = "." Then
            nrTextboxes = nrTextboxes + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("Found " & nrTextboxes & " textboxes.")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me.

The only way to do this, really (aside from recreating the text box from scratch), is copy/paste. That will carry across all the formatting.

Key aspects about this approach:

**Setting the target page**: Word doesn't have "page" objects, due to its dynamic layout behavior. `Selection.GoTo` is the simplest method to get a page. Since the text boxes are formatted relative to the page, it doesn't matter where on the page the anchor is attached. (Unless there's going to be a lot of subsequent editing that could push the anchoring range to a different page.) So this code assigns the first paragraph's range to be the anchor.

**Identifying the text box(es) to be copied**: It's not necessary to *select* a text box in order to work with its content. The text can be read from `TextFrame.TextRange.Text`.

**Looping with multiple text boxes**: As soon as a text box is created (pasted) in the target range, Word will say "Aha! there's another text box!" and will try to loop that, too, which is not what is wanted. So the code in the question has been modified to add the text boxes which should be copied to *an array* (`shps()`). Once all the text boxes that need to be copied have been identified, the code then loops this array, copies each text box and paste it to the target range.

```
Sub searchTexboxes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim shps() As Shape
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim nrTextboxes As Integer
    Dim target As Word.Range
    Dim targetPage As Long, i As Long

    nrTextboxes = 0
    targetPage = 1
    Selection.GoTo What:=Word.wdGoToPage, Which:=targetPage
    Set target = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            sTemp = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            sTemp = Left(sTemp, 1)
            If sTemp = "." Then
                nrTextboxes = nrTextboxes + 1
                ReDim Preserve shps(nrTextboxes - 1)
                Set shps(nrTextboxes - 1) = shp
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For i = LBound(shps) To UBound(shps)
                shps(i).Select
                Selection.Copy
                target.Paste
    Next
    MsgBox ("Found " & nrTextboxes & " textboxes.")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the order of the shapes in ActiveDocument.Shapes? When I originally created the textboxes, are they ordered in the sequence I created them? Are the copied text boxes appended to the ActiveDocument.Shapes array?

Comment: The order of Shapes will be the order of their *anchor* in the document. So a Shape that appears higher on the page than another *could* come later in the collection if its anchor-point is lower on the page. The copied text boxes are added to the document's `Shapes` *collection*, which is why the code in my answer first makes an array of the Shapes already in the document that match the criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yes, I understand the design of your code. I was just wondering how I can distribute the pre-defined text boxes in a specific sequence over the whole document. But I guess one possible solution is to add a number in white font colour that is the _index_ of the textbox in the sequence. (My ultimate goal is kind of a post-it animation. So the idea is to align dots along a path on one page and then distribute them in the right sequence over all the other pages. So when you flip through the document you'd see the animation)

Comment: @piiipmatz OK... I sort of understand what you're saying, but if you want help with it you'll need to ask a new question and provide very clear information. That said... Why not use **tables**?